# Handling Ctrl+<...> KeyCodes beyond the basics

Tags: elm

I'm trying to implement `ctrl-x/v` for an editing app (not of text but of things depicted on the screen, so I can't just use browser copy/paste).

It's all working with the following setup:

- a KeyDown message - triggered by the Keyboard library - sets `model.ctrlPressed` toTrue (on KeyCode 17)
- a KeyUp handler to reverse that.

However, it has occurred several time that I can be pressing the ctrl button when I click away and then the `KeyUp` is never passed to Elm and `model.ctrlPressed` gets stuck in the wrong state.

So I tried the `PageVisibility` library and - on a `Hidden` subscription - I set ctrlPressed to False. That helps if I minimise the browser or switch tab, but not for the instance where I was holding ctrl when clicking on the dev console.

Maybe this is an error that will only really happen in development, but I don't want to take that risk. Anyone have suggestions for a way out of this?

Answer (score 0):

**You want [`document.hasFocus()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/hasFocus).** It doesn't fire an event though, you have to poll for it.

Here's an example ([run](https://ellie-app.com/3c8FQWYTX6Ra1/1)):

```
port module Main exposing (..)

import Html as H exposing (Html)
import Time


port focusStateRequest : () -> Cmd msg


port focusStateResponse : (Bool -> msg) -> Sub msg


type alias Model =
    { windowFocused : Bool }


type Msg
    = FocusStateRequest
    | FocusStateResponse Bool


main : Program Never Model Msg
main =
    H.program
        { init = init
        , update = update
        , view = view
        , subscriptions = subscriptions
        }


init : ( Model, Cmd Msg )
init =
    ( { windowFocused = True }
    , Cmd.none
    )


update : Msg -> Model -> ( Model, Cmd Msg )
update msg model =
    case msg of
        FocusStateRequest ->
            ( model
            , focusStateRequest ()
            )

        FocusStateResponse isFocused ->
            -- reset your ctrlPressed here if False
            ( { model | windowFocused = isFocused }
            , Cmd.none
            )


view : Model -> Html Msg
view model =
    model
        |> toString
        |> H.text


subscriptions : Model -> Sub Msg
subscriptions model =
    Sub.batch
        [ Time.every (500 * Time.millisecond) (\_ -> FocusStateRequest)
        , focusStateResponse FocusStateResponse
        ]
```

And on the JS side:

```
var app = Elm.Main.fullscreen();

app.ports.focusStateRequest.subscribe(function() {
  var hasFocus = document.hasFocus();
  app.ports.focusStateResponse.send(hasFocus);
});
```